# can i know abt the exit status of the scp command in unix

Tags: unix, ssh, scp

while doing the programing in perl with scp command 
i am stucked with facing the exit status of scp command

if you tell  which exit value(other then 0-success,1-error) is for what my life will be simple

Answer (score 8):

From [here](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2116.html):

```
0   Operation was successful
1   General error in file copy
2   Destination is not directory, but it should be
3   Maximum symlink level exceeded
4   Connecting to host failed.
5   Connection broken
6   File does not exist
7   No permission to access file.
8   General error in sftp protocol
9   File transfer protocol mismatch
10  No file matches a given criteria
65  Host not allowed to connect
66  General error in ssh protocol
67  Key exchange failed
68  Reserved
69  MAC error
70  Compression error
71  Service not available
72  Protocol version not supported
73  Host key not verifiable
74  Connection failed
75  Disconnected by application
76  Too many connections
77  Authentication cancelled by user
78  No more authentication methods available
79  Invalid user name
```

Answer (score 2):

link: [scp return codes](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2116.html)

Answer (score 0):

0 is almost always the success return code, when dealing with shell commands and similar programs.