# Actual return code for SCP

Tags: bash, error-handling, scp

I am writing a bash script that goes through a list of filenames and attempts to copy each file using `scp` from two servers into a local folder. The script then compares the local files to each other. Sometimes however, the file will not exist on one server or the other or both.

At first, I was using this code:

```
scp $user@$host:/etc/$file ./$host/conf/ 2>/tmp/Error 1>/dev/null
error=$(</tmp/Error) # error catching
if [[ -n "$error" ]]; then echo -e "$file not found on $host"; fi
```

But I found that some (corporate) servers output a (legalese) message (to stderr I guess) every time a user connects via `scp` or `ssh`. So I started looking into utilizing [exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921210/can-i-know-abt-the-exit-status-of-the-scp-command-in-unix).

I could simply use

```
scp $user@$host:/etc/$file ./$host/conf/ 2>/tmp/Error 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo -e "$file not found on $host"; fi
```

but since the [exit code for "file does not exist" is supposed to be 6](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2116.html#SCP_Return_Codes), I would rather have a more precise

```
scp $user@$host:/etc/$file ./$host/conf/ 2>/tmp/Error 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 6 ]]; then echo -e "$file not found on $host"; fi
```

The problem is that I seem to be getting an exit code of 1 no matter what went wrong. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944534/catching-errors-in-scp-or-sftp), but that answer does not help me in Bash.

Another solution I am considering is

```
scp $user@$host:/etc/$file ./$host/conf/ 2>/tmp/Error 1>/dev/null
error=$(</tmp/Error) # error catching
if [[ ${error: -25} = "No such file or directory" ]]; then echo -e "$file not found on $host"; fi
```

But I am concerned that different versions of `scp` could have different error messages for the same error.

Is there a way to get the actual exit code of `scp` in a Bash script?

Comment: Use a `case` statement: `case $? in (0) echo ok ;; (6) echo "file not found";; (*) echo "something else";; esac`. Or save the return code in a variable: `ret_code=$?`. As a side note: don't use `scp`, it's very bad. Prefer `rsync` or `sftp` instead.

Comment: To be clear the return code you get from `scp` relates to its status on the local machine; it doesn't pass through the return code from the remote machine being copied from.  So it will have a non-zero exit code if for example, the host doesn't exist, or credentials fail.  Maybe this is clear, if so, just ignore the comment.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is expressing what I would say, except I would use `rsync` period. My experience is that `scp` is less bad that `sftp`! ;-) When I had to  `ftp` between multiple OSs, I had a function that had knowledge of each OS's ftp's error messages and acted accordingly.
Also, haven't used `rsync` on enough OSs to know if the error messages are consistent. I think the should be, but ... if it has to be bullet-proof, assume the worst, and test every case specially during your development. Good luck!

Comment: The scp return codes on the page you linked are, unfortunately, specific to Attachmate. OpenSSH's scp, perhaps the most common and apparently the implementation on your machine, returns 1 for very nearly every error condition. I'm afraid I can offer no solution, but perhaps this'll save you some searching in hopeless directions.

Comment: @shellter Ooops I can't believe I wrote that! I really meant: _`scp` and `sftp` are bad, use `rsync` or `ssh` instead_.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : LOL, yeah why can't we just install one perfectly correct file transfer program on all machines world-wide and be done with it! ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments ([@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf), [@shelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter), [@Wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute)) I decided to simply switch tools to `rsync`. Thankfully the syntax doesn't need to be changed at all.

`23` was the error code I was getting when files didn't exist so here is the code I ended up with

```
rsync -q $user@$host:/etc/$file ./$host/conf/ 2>/tmp/Error 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 23 ]]; then echo -e "$file not found on $host"; continue; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing 1 for "file not found" not found,  you can do testing for these sorts of things against localhost,  if you need to differentiate different errors capture stdout instead.

```
if $err=`scp $host:$file 2>&1`
then 
  echo "copied successfully
else
case "$err" in 
  *"file not found"* )
     echo "$file Not Found on $host"
     ;;
  *"Could not resolve hostname"* )
    echo "Host not found: $host"
    ;;
  "Permission denied "* ) 
    echo "perm-denied! $host" 
    ;;
  * )
    echo "other scp error $err"
    ;;
esac
```

this isn't going to work if you have a different locale with different messages.

Comment: My question is attempting to get a reliable exit status from `scp` and as we both mention I can't rely on regular expression based error output. In fact, the case statement you list ("file not found") would not find the error statement I'm seeing which is "No such file or directory".