# Checking the exit status of a ssh remote command in bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to check that a transacions file is published on a remote host. There is no transactions code published for today the 31 of December.
I know that for certain. There is one for yesterday. However no matter which date I use, the 30 or the 31, the return code is the same.

What I am looking to check is the  return status of ssh which I thought should be return status of the remotely executed command
I thought that the 'if statement' would exit with a 0 if the 'ls -ltr' worked and something greater than zero, or false if the 'ls -ltr' did not 
work. I would think that the 'if' statement would look at the return status of the shh, which should be the return status of the remotely 
executed command - or the 'ls -ltr'

How do i get thie to work?

this is for the 30 - which is on the remote host, and is successful

```
casper@host:/scripts$ ssh -q -T user@capserbox "ls -ltr  /home/DropBox/transactions_20141230.csv"
-rw-r--r--   1 rr_prd    2233047 Dec 31 07:26 /home/DropBox/transactions_20141230.csv
```

and this is for the 31 which there is no report yet for the 31, so it is unsuccessful

```
casper@host:/scripts$ ssh -q -T user@capserbox "ls -ltr  /home/DropBox/transactions_20141231.csv"
/home/DropBox/transactions_20141231.csv not found
casper@host:/scripts$
```

I flip the date with the comment out hashtag

```
casper@host:/scripts$ ssh -q -T user@capserbox "ls -ltr  /home/DropBox/transactions_20141231.csv"
/home/DropBox/transactions_20141231.csv not found
casper@host:/scripts$



#!/bin/bash
today=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
#today="20141230"
echo $today
if ssh -q -T user@capserbox "ls -ltr  /home/DropBox/transactions_$today.csv" > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
    then
       echo "this worked"
    else
       echo "this did not work"
fi
```

However - when i use the script for both dates  - it is successful, when for the 31, it really should return "this did not work"

```
casper@host:/scripts$
casper@host:/scripts$ vim offshore_check
casper@host:/scripts$ ./offshore_check
20141230
this worked
casper@host:/scripts$ vim offshore_check
casper@host:/scripts$ ./offshore_check
20141231
this worked
casper@host:/scripts$
casper@host:/scripts$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "if" construct that you're using should work, and it does work for me:

```
$ if ssh -q -T localhost "ls -ltr /does/not/exist"; then echo succeeded; else echo failed; fi
Password:
ls: /does/not/exist: No such file or directory
failed
```

I notice that the error printed by your `ls` program is worded differently than the error that I got (and I tried two different systems). "file not found" in your case, "ls: file: No such file or directory" in mine.  My suspicion is that the `ls` command which you're invoking here isn't the typical modern Unix command. You may be running a nonstandard version, a non-Unix version, or something very old, and it may not actually be exiting with a non-zero exit code for this particular error.

Comment: it is an older offshore machine  - - SunOS 5.8 Generic_117350-35 - build-version 020

Answer (score 2):

```
file="/home/DropBox/transactions_20141231.csv"
ssh -q -T user@capserbox "test -e $file"
ret="$?"
case $ret in
  0)
    echo "$file exists"
    ;;
  1)
    echo "$file does not exist"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "other problem"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues have been discussed here many times, see [scp return code discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713728/actual-return-code-for-scp#comment43840790_27713728)

and 300+ answers when [searching for scp errors](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scp%20error%20codes)

but to give you a working answer, consider trying this

```
 if 
     ssh -q -T user@capserbox "ls -ltr  /home/DropBox/transactions_${today}.csv" \
     | grep -q "transactions_${today}\.csv" ;
 then
       echo "this worked" 
 else
       echo "nope"
 fi
```

Sorry, I don't have any way to test this.

IHTH.